# Ajax and Jquery via dropdowns and comprehensions enhancement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

http://graphnickdesign.com/blog/generating-dynamic-selection-dropdown-jquery-ajax/

I was looking at this website and was trying to emulate this example http://graphnickdesign.com/demo/ajax-selection-generation/, I then attempted to get the source code and tried to just see the example with my computer, is it possible to use this code and if so how can I put format to make it work. I also attempted to link the xml file as we..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Select Country</title>
<link href="oneColFixCtrHdr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(init);
    //var mainXML;
    var curProgram="";
    var curLanguage="";
     function init(){
    $("#languageList").hide();
    loadXML("langSelections.xml");
}
function loadXML(_xml){
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: _xml,
         dataType: "xml",
         success: setXML
}) // close ajax
}
function setXML(_xml){
     var _idx=0;
     var curOption;
     var curCountry = $(_xml).find('country')
     $(curCountry).each(function(i){
         var country = $(this);
         curOption=$("<option value='" + $(country).attr('program') + "'>" +    c country.children('label').text() + "</option>")
        curOption.data("country",country); // bind the country node data from the XML to the option of the dropdown
         $(curOption).appendTo($('#countryList'))
    })
}
function setLanguage(){
    var curCountry = $('#countryList').children(':selected').data('country')
    $('#languageList').html(""); // reset the languages list
    var curLang = $(curCountry).find('language');
    $('#linkURL').html("");
      if (curLang.length>1){
        curLang.each(function(i){
            var lang = $(this);
            var langCode=lang.attr('langCode');
            if (i==0){
                 curOption="<option value='null'>--Select Language--</option><option value='" + langCode + "'>" + lang.text() + "</option>";
             }else{
                 curOption+="<option value='" + langCode + "'>" + lang.text() + "</option>"
            }
         });
        $(curOption).appendTo($('#languageList'));
        $('#languageList').show()
    }else if (curCountry==null){
        $('#languageList').hide();

    }else{
        $('#languageList').hide();
        gotoPage($(curCountry).find('language').attr('langCode'))
    }
}
function gotoPage(_lang){
        if (_lang==null){
            _lang = $('#languageList').val();
    }
    if (_lang!="null"){
            var _url = "<p>http://myURL/" + $('#countryList').val() + "/"+ _lang;
         //window.open(_url)
        $('#linkURL').html(_url);
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Generate Selections With XML</h1>
    <form id="selections" >
        <select name="countrySelect" onchange="setLanguage()" id="countryList">
            <option value="null">--Select Country--</option>
        </select>
        <select name="languageSelect" onchange="gotoPage()" id="languageList">
        </select>

    </form>
    <p id="linkURL"></p>
    <!-- end .content --></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <!-- end .footer --></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the XLM code

```
<countries>
<country program="1">
    <label>United States</label>
    <languages>
        <language langCode="en_US">English</language>
    </languages>
</country>
<country program="13">
    <label>Canada</label>
    <languages>
        <language langCode="en_US">English</language>
        <language langCode="ca_FR">FranÃ§ais</language>
    </languages>
</country>
<country program="10">
    <label>Mexico</label>
    <languages>
        <language langCode="en_US">English</language>
        <language langCode="es_MX">EspaÃ±ol</language>
    </languages>
</country>
```

What am I missing to complete this example as seen above

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I am currently using notepad ++ and there is no error, I cannot get it to work at all, the select is present but I cannot see the information populated from the XML